# regex - preg_replace in my PHP script doesn't work

Tags: regex, tinymce, preg-replace

I've a form where I take a HTML code from a TinyMCE editor as input in one of my textarea to make a newsletter. I'd like add utm codes at the end of every link. I simulated a RegEX pattern and replacement to online editor but the saved code is the usual href without utm codes.

```
<?php
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$from_email=$_POST['from_email'];
$from_name=$_POST['from_name'];
$replyto_email=$_POST['replyto_email'];
$replyto_name=$_POST['replyto_name'];
$lingua=$_POST['lingua'];
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['editor1']) ;

$string = $body;
$pattern = '/href="([^"]+)/';
$replacement = '$0?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign='.$subject;
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

$stmt=null;
$stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter_email(subject,from_email,from_name,replyto_email,replyto_name,lingua,body) VALUES('$subject','$from_email','$from_name','$replyto_email','$replyto_name','$lingua','$txt')");
if (!$stmt) {
  log_msg($db->error);
  die();
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

**Example of $body content from TinyMCE**

```
$body = "<html><head></head><body><a href="example.com" target="_blank">Test</a></body></html>"
```

**Example of $body content after preg_replace**

```
$body = "<html><head></head><body><a href="example.com?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Email Subject" target="_blank">Test</a></body></html>"
```

Comment: An explicit easy-to-catch pair of input and expected output is always welcome while asking RegEx questions.

Comment: You're right. Here:

`<a href="example.com">` --> `<a href="example.com?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Email subject">`

Comment: Your replacement string is incomplete. It should be `$replacement = 'href="$1?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign='.$subject;`

Comment: @revo same problem of before :(

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: @revo this one, like regex didn't affect:
`<a href="example.com">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

> mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['editor1'])

It adds '\' between tags and the pattern doesn't match. It's changed (pay attention to '.')

> $pattern = '/href=."([^"]+)/';

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to do the replacement with `$0` instead of `$1`:

```
$subject = 'Email subject';
$string = '<a href="example.com">';
$pattern = '/href="([^"]+)/';
$replacement = '$0?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign='.$subject;
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

echo $txt;
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="example.com?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Email subject">
```

Comment: OP has an issue that probably overrides any prior changes. I think he doesn't work with right variable otherwise his problem should be solved by comments.

Comment: It works when i put something in $string variable as example, but not when $string take the content of the $body that i get from TinyMCE editor in this way:

`$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['editor1']) ;`

$body contains multiple lines with the entire HTML, example:

`<html><head></head><body><a href="example.com"></body></html>`

Sorry, I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Otto:It works for me even in a whole html page, the link is changed as requested. Please, edit your question with a full reproductible example and what you want as output.